# Need image editor in website to edit image

Tags: jquery

i am looking for jquery image editor any one has idea or link please help me.
i want editor like [demo](http://www.spreadshirt.co.uk/design-your-own-t-shirt-C59)

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: Man i am not sure this work or not i need just hint which one is the good way to do this. i google for this and got some useful link but i need just hint to do this. and can i do using like this $("#theDiv").append("<img id='theImg' src='theImg.png'/>");

Comment: @RohitGilbile use the edit button below your question to update it and provide more info and the some of the code you have tried so far. Just asking a recommendation for a tool is considered here off topic and your post will be closed. You can read here about it http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is basically a text editor with an image uploading capability.

There are some in this link.

http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-wysiwyg-editor/

Comment: Thanks jerr..your link was very help full me

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to mark my answer as the correct answer (:

Comment: Just click on the tick :D